# Hosting Django on Google cloud 502 error

Tags: django, google-cloud-platform

Good day. 
I'm a newbie to GCP. I followed the steps on the site on how to host a Python app using the app engine. However when I try to access the site on myfirstestever.appspot.com, it returns a 502 error. 
I dont know what is wrong or what to do about it. I'm a newbie. 
How can I solve this? Thanks.

app.yaml file

> entrypoint: gcloud app browse 
>      env: flex
>      runtime: python

Note: the app is written using Python 3.5 and Django 1.10

Comment: please check the log file

Comment: The log file? Where? How? I don't understand.

Comment: if you are using apache then, /var/log/httpd/error.log or something like that

Comment: Does this happen while running in your local development environment? What does the console show?

You can also see the GCP logs by going to cloud.google.com -> clicking console -> selecting your project and clicking "logging"

Comment: No, it has never happened in my local environment. The console shows "cannot read property 'parent Node' of undefined". I however have not been able to access the logging on the console. I'm still looking

Comment: Can you provide the link you followed? And if possible, your app.yaml

Comment: @Kenworth I've edited the question to provide the app.yaml file. The link I followed is https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/quickstart

Answer (score 1):

`gcloud app browse` is a command to open your application on the browser. It's basically just typing your URL on the browser. An example entrypoint for Django would be: `entrypoint: gunicorn -b :$PORT mysite.wsgi` For a more Django-specific App Engine Flex tutorial, click [here](https://cloud.google.com/python/django/flexible-environment).

Comment: Sorry for not getting back to you. I got really busy with exams and projects. So I looked into my logs and realized that the problem is gunicorn. I searched the net and it seems gunicorn is not supported on Windows.

Comment: I've switched over to Ubuntu but it's still giving the same error

Comment: What can I do again?. I'm going mad here.